# How can i pass the data of the selected filter chip to other page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

I want to pass the data of the selected filter chip on the previous page and navigate it to the next page with additional text on that respective chip.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the chip's value when it is pressed to the next page right ?
If that is the case you have multiple options:

1. push the value with the route using route arguments.
2. declare an attribute in the destination page of the required type, and pass the value of choice by constructor.
3. using state management solutions, which are plenty.

If I missed your point please let me know.